# How to keep only certain values from a dataframe based on their preceding values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (call it df) with data that looks like that (image below). And would like to obtain a new df (call it df2) that is 0 everywhere UNLESS both of these conditions are true

- Corresponding df value was 1
- It is preceeded by 10 zeros

I tried something like this but it makes everything zero:

```
df2 = df.copy()

for col in df2.columns:
    count_zeros = 0
    for i in range(1, len(df2)):
        if df2[col][i] == 1 and count_zeros == 10:
            df2[col][i] = 1
            count_zeros = 0
        elif df2[col][i] == 1:
            df2[col][i] = 0
            count_zeros = 0
        else:
            count_zeros += 1
```

[image: Data Sample]

For example, there, only the first column x 8/11/23 and third column 8/16/23 should stay 1, everything else 0

Comment: Provide `df2.sample(20).to_dict()` output by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76978378/edit) the post.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have should work except that your condition where `count==10`.  Currently, your code is looking for a very specific condition, that `i` is `1` and `count` is exactly `10`.

Change it to `count>=10` and it should work.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing came into my mind is to use the rolling function which is very clean but definitely not the most efficient if your dataset is huge.

Here is the code:

```py
df2 = df.copy()
template = np.array([0]*9 +[1]) # [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]
for col in df2.columns:
  df[col] = df[col].rolling(10).apply(lambda x: int(all(x.values==template))).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this where n is the consecutive amount of 0's needed:

```
n = 10
(df.where(
    df.eq(0).cumsum().sub(df.eq(0).cumsum().where(df.ne(0))
         .ffill()
         .fillna(0))
         .ge(n)
         .shift(fill_value=False),0))
```

or

```
n = 10
df.where(df.eq(0).rolling(n).sum().eq(5).shift() & df.eq(1),0)
```